# Subtracting the mean from every row of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a $N \times D$ matrix

$$\mathbf{Y} = \begin{bmatrix} — \mathbf{y}_1^\top — \\ — \mathbf{y}_2^\top — \\ \vdots\\ — \mathbf{y}_N^\top —\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\mathbf{y}_i^\top$ are row vectors. I am told in the book that I am reading that subtracting the vector

$$\bar{\mathbf{y}} := \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}{\mathbf{y}_n}$$

individually from every column in $\mathbf{Y}$ will make the mean zero. Firstly, why is this true?

Now I experimented a little and realized that adding ALL the matrix elements together and dividing by $N*D$ also makes the mean of $\mathbf{Y}$ zero. Was this just a special or is it generally true that the two methods for normalizing are same? I cannot see why they would be, so could anyone please convince me?

In fact, you get two different matrices but both with a mean of 0 :/

Comment: Yup :) I'll include that

Comment: I think so except for the 1 at the first row

Comment: Yes, I don't see anything wrong. However, I do not really mind all these edits. I hope for an answer to my question :)))))

Comment: Ahh, I see :) You subtract each column in Y by the mean of this column-

Comment: I do not understand you. Where do you see a scalar in uppercase`?

Comment: Ahh well but all I have seen is dimensions given in uppercase. But anyway, we are moving away from the question and don't wanna extend the comment section more with cosmetics :====))) Thanks for the input though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$\mathbf{Y} = \begin{bmatrix} — \mathbf{y}_1^\top — \\ — \mathbf{y}_2^\top — \\ \vdots\\ — \mathbf{y}_n^\top —\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\mathbf{y}_i^\top \in \mathbb R^d$. Let the average of the rows be

$$\bar{\mathbf{y}}^\top := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\mathbf{y}_i}^\top = \frac 1n \mathbf{1}_n^\top \mathbf{Y}$$

Subtracting the average from every row,

$$\mathbf{Y} - \mathbf{1}_n \bar{\mathbf{y}}^\top = \cdots = \left( \mathbf{I}_n -  \frac 1n \mathbf{1}_n \mathbf{1}_n^\top \right) \mathbf{Y}$$

and, thus,

$$\mathbf{1}_n^\top \left( \mathbf{Y} - \mathbf{1}_n \bar{\mathbf{y}}^\top \right) = \cdots = \mathbf{0}_n^\top$$

Comment: Uhhh I am starting to realize something! But is the $\mathbf{1}$ the identity matrix or? And why is $\bar{\mathbf{y}}^\top := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\mathbf{y}_i}^\top = \frac 1n \mathbf{1}_n^\top \mathbf{Y}$? I really appreciate it!

Comment: $\mathbf{1}_n$ is the $n$-dimensional vector of ones. $\mathbf{I}_n$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: Okay. thought you just used a different notation :) What about my second question? Thanks again

Comment: Left-multiply by $\mathbf{1}_n^\top$ and you add rows. Right-multiply by $\mathbf{1}_n$ and you add columns.